# Vertical scroll slider with anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, slider

I'm a JavaScript novice and I'm trying to make something on my own. In this case I've created a fake vertical slider that actually works with the normal page scroll. However, I've chosen to insert a menu on the right-hand side which allows you to navigate between the slider elements by means of anchor links.
Next to this menu there is a svg representing an upward and a downward arrow which can act as trigger points to scroll between the slider elements.

I have set up the highlighting of the active element and I was able to set the anchor link to the click of the arrows and the recognition of the next or previous one.

What I can't manage to set is the synchronisation between the various scroll options. In fact, if I scroll with the mouse or click on one of the elements, the arrows do not update their position.

I hope I can explain this.

I share the reference JSFiddle. (Sorry for the spartan graphic appearance).

You can see it better implemented [here](https://development.nutfordesign.com/product-parallax-scroll/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $currentElement = $(".single-product").first();

  $("#down").click(function() {
    var $nextElement = $currentElement.next('.single-product');
    // Check if the next element exists by measuring its length
    if ($nextElement.length) {
      // Se esiste, aggiorna l'elemento corrente e scorre
      $currentElement = $nextElement;
      $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
        scrollTop: $nextElement.offset().top
      }, 1000);
    }
    return false;
  });

  $("#up").click(function() {
    var $prevElement = $currentElement.prev('.single-product');
    // Check if the next element exists by measuring its length
    if ($prevElement.length) {
      // Se esiste, aggiorna l'elemento corrente e scorre
      $currentElement = $prevElement;
      $('html, body').stop(true).animate({
        scrollTop: $prevElement.offset().top
      }, 1000);
    }
    return false;
  });

  //highlight anchor link on scroll

  // Cache selectors
  var topMenu = $("#product-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight() + 100,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function() {
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) {
        return item;
      }
    });

  // Bind to scroll
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    // Get container scroll position
    var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop() + topMenuHeight;

    // Get id of current scroll item
    var cur = scrollItems.map(function() {
      if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
        return this;
    });

    // Get the id of the current element
    cur = cur[cur.length - 1];
    var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";
    // Set/remove active class
    menuItems
      .parent().removeClass("active")
      .end().filter("[href='#" + id + "']").parent().addClass("active");
  });
});
```

```css
.scroll-slider-container{
  display:flex;
  align-items:flex-start;
}
.product-container{
  width:70%;
}
.navigation-container{
  width:30%;
  position:fixed;
  right:0;
}

.single-product{
  height:700px;
  background: url(https://development.nutfordesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/img-slide-1.png);
}

#product-menu{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
 #menu-product-side-menu{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    justify-content:flex-end; 
  }
 .nav-arrows{
   width:30px;
 }
 .active{
    font-weight:700!important;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll-slider-container">
<div class="product-container">
<div id="product-1" class="single-product">
<h2>Prodotto 1</h2>
</div>
<div id="product-2" class="single-product">
<h2>Prodotto 2</h2>
</div>
<div id="product-3" class="single-product">
<h2>Prodotto 3</h2>
</div>
<div id="product-4" class="single-product">
<h2>Prodotto 4</h2>
</div>
</div>
<div id="product-menu" class="navigation-container">
<ul id="menu-product-side-menu "class="nav-list">
<li><a href="#product-1">Prodotto 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#product-2">Prodotto 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#product-3">Prodotto 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#product-4">Prodotto 4</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="nav-arrows">
<svg version="1.1" id="double-arrow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
     y="0px" viewBox="0 0 200 2000" style="enable-background:new 0 0 200 2000;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{opacity:2.000000e-02;fill:#FFFFFF;}
    .st1{fill:#1D1D1B;}
</style>
<a href="" id="down" class=" arrow next">
   <g>
    <rect y="1000" class="st0" width="200" height="1000"/>
    <path id="arrow-down" class="st1" d="M168.9,1867.9c-1.4-1.4-3.8-1.4-5.2,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l-60,60V1000h-7.4v927.9l-60-60
        c-1.4-1.4-3.8-1.4-5.2,0s-1.4,3.8,0,5.2l0,0l66.3,66.3c1.4,1.4,3.8,1.4,5.2,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l66.3-66.3
        C170.3,1871.7,170.3,1869.4,168.9,1867.9z"/>
</g>
  </a>
  
  <a href="" id="up" class="arrow prev">  
  <g>
    <rect class="st0" width="200" height="1000"/>
    <path id="arrow-up" class="st1" d="M168.9,132.1c-1.4,1.4-3.8,1.4-5.2,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l-60-60V1000h-7.4V72.1l-60,60
        c-1.4,1.4-3.8,1.4-5.2,0s-1.4-3.8,0-5.2l0,0l66.3-66.3c1.4-1.4,3.8-1.4,5.2,0c0,0,0,0,0,0l66.3,66.3
        C170.4,128.3,170.4,130.6,168.9,132.1C168.9,132.1,168.9,132.1,168.9,132.1z"/>
</g>
</a>
</svg>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The site you referenced isn't working

Comment: Here the example https://development.nutfordesign.com/product-parallax-scroll/